# Not sure how to loop in SQL over this data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to forumlate a query which will give me this result:

For each quiz number list the quiz number and the average high score. Only include the quizzes that more than 10 students took.

The query I am formulating looks like this:

```
SELECT QuizNum, AVG(HighScore) from quizzes WHERE NumStudents > 10;
```

This, however, gives me :

```
1, 20.75000
```

Which is incorrect data. I just really don't know where to start with this one.

The table looks like this:

```
'QuizNum', 'decimal(2,0)', 'NO', 'PRI', '0', ''
'QuizDate', 'date', 'NO', 'PRI', '0000-00-00', ''
'HighScore', 'decimal(3,1)', 'YES', '', '', ''
'LowScore', 'decimal(3,1)', 'YES', '', '', ''
'AvgScore', 'decimal(3,1)', 'YES', '', '', ''
'NumStudents', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', '', ''
'NumPassing', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', '', ''
```

So, foe example, every date quiz one occured has more than 10 students, so I need its average. Then I need the next quiz. 
Table Contents:

```
1, '2009-01-25', 20.0, 9.0, 12.5, 15, 10
1, '2009-06-15', 30.0, 22.0, 25.6, , 
1, '2009-08-25', , , , 15, 10
1, '2010-01-24', 20.0, 9.0, 12.5, 17, 14
1, '2010-06-14', 28.5, 21.0, 26.6, 25, 25
1, '2010-08-24', , , , 21, 18
2, '2009-03-06', 18.0, 10.5, 15.0, 15, 12
2, '2009-07-01', 28.5, 18.5, 23.4, , 
2, '2009-09-21', 18.0, 10.5, 15.0, 15, 12
2, '2010-03-05', 18.5, 11.5, 15.2, 17, 14
2, '2010-06-30', 30.0, 25.0, 27.4, 23, 23
2, '2010-09-20', , , , 22, 19
3, '2009-03-24', 19.0, 14.5, 17.8, 13, 13
3, '2009-08-01', 27.5, 25.0, 16.2, , 
3, '2009-10-12', 19.0, 14.5, 17.8, 13, 13
3, '2010-03-23', 20.0, 17.0, 18.6, 16, 16
3, '2010-07-31', , , , 23, 20
3, '2010-10-11', 20.0, 9.0, 13.8, 22, 17
4, '2009-04-14', 20.0, 15.5, , , 
4, '2009-11-22', 20.0, 15.5, 17.9, , 
4, '2010-04-13', 20.0, 12.5, , , 
4, '2010-11-21', 20.0, 7.5, 13.9, 20, 15
5, '2009-05-04', 17.0, 8.5, 10.7, 10, 7
5, '2009-12-09', 17.0, 8.5, 10.7, 10, 7
5, '2010-04-03', 19.5, 11.5, 15.7, 15, 13
5, '2010-12-08', 20.0, 15.0, 17.3, 18, 18
```

Ideas?

Comment: Expected output? what is NumStudents?

Comment: I will update the question to show you the table contents. There are 5 numbers of quizzes. For each quiz number, I need the quiznumber and average of the high score column.  Only for quizzes where more than 10 students took the quiz. I just dont know how to iterate over a column in this fasion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For each quiz number

You need a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT QuizNum, AVG(HighScore) 
FROM quizzes 
WHERE NumStudents > 10 
GROUP BY QuizNum;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `GROUP BY` clause like

```
SELECT QuizNum,
       AVG(HighScore)
FROM quizzes
WHERE NumStudents > 10
GROUP BY QuizNum;
```